# Python truncating numbers in integer array

Tags: python, list, function

I am teaching myself Python and am running into a strange problem. What I am trying to do is pass a list to a function, and have the function return a list where elements are the sum of the numbers around it, but what I thought would work produced some strange results, so I made a debug version of the code that still exhibts the behavior, which is as follows:

When I make an integer array, and pass it to an function which then uses a for loop print the individual values of the list, the numbers following the first one in each int are truncated.

For example, the following input and output:

```
Please enter a number: 101
Please enter a number: 202
Please enter a number: 303
Please enter a number: .
1
2
3
```

This happens no matter the input, if its 10, 101, or 13453 - the same behavior happens.

I know I am probably missing something simple, but for the sake of me, no amount of googling yields me a solution to this issue. Attached below is the code I am using to execute this. It is interesting to note: when printing the entire list outside of the for loop at any point, it returns the full and proper list (ie ['101', '202', '303'])

Thanks!

```
temp = list()

def sum(list):
    print list
    for i in range(1, len(list)+1):
        print i
    return temp

L = list()
while True:
    input = raw_input("Please enter a number: ");
    if input.strip() == ".":
        break
    L.append(input);

print L

L2 = sum(L)
print L2
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, probably a copy/paste error.

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` and `input` as variable names, because they will shadow their corresponding built-in functions.

Comment: Are you aware that the values you are appending to `L` are strings, and not integers?

Comment: @JoelCornett No, I wasn't aware...is there a guide you can point me towards that will clarify this. I thought Python casted variable around as needed...similar to Ruby

Comment: @Suki: Python does dynamically type variables, but in this case, you are accepting string input. So the variable is typed as a string. When you do operations to that variable, python will perform string operations on it. You can use `userInput = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))`. That will convert the value passed to `userInput` to an integer. Read the python docs at [python.org](www.python.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop

```
for i in range(1, len(my_list)+1):
    print i
```

iterates over the numbers from 1 to `len(my_list)`, not over the items of the list.  To do the latter, use

```
for x in my_list:
    print x
```

(I've renamed `list` to `my_list` to save you another headache.)

Comment: Thank you! Now what I need to know though is: using the for x in my_list method you described is there any easy way to sum together numbers in a method similar to Java. Using i+1 / i / i-1 for example, adding all the neighbors of a list together in a list such that if L1 = [1, 2, 3] then L2 = [3, 6, 5] [1+2, 1+2+3, 2+3] where normally I would do number = i-1 + i + i+1 (with the appropriate error checking ofc)

Comment: @Suki: You aren't asking for a clarification, you are asking a completely new question.  Please use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page to enable other people than me to see the new question.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the counter, not the list item.  This is what you want:

```
for i in list:
    print i
```

list is itself iterable and you don't need a counter to loop it.